# Infinite loop when subclassing MKAnnotationView and calling init from initWithFrame: overloads

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Having this XCTestCase case:

```
- (void)testAllInitializersConfigureTheView {
    BIStationAnnotationView *withFrame = [[BIStationAnnotationView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
    XCTAssertTrue(CGRectEqualToRect(withFrame.frame, CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 30.f, 40.f)), @"Frame should be fixed");
}
```

Testing a subclass of [MKAnnotationView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/):

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.frame = _myFrame;
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    return self = [self init];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    return self = [self init];
}
```

I get an infinite loop because `initWithFrame` calls `init` and `init` calls `initWithFrame`.

[image]

Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C there is the concept of the designated initializer which is the most important and usually most specific initializer. In addition, there may be convenience initializers with a shorter signature that internally call the designated initializer. Cocoa follows this pattern which means that the convenience initializer `[UIView init]` calls the designated initializer `[UIView initWithFrame:]`.

In your particular case, you're calling the convenience initializer `[self init]` from the designated initializer `[self initWithFrame:]`. This is wrong because `[self init]` will call `[super init]` (which is `[UIView init]`) and that one follows the designated initializer concept and calls `[self initWithFrame]`.

To resolve this issue you should call `[super initWithFrame:]` from within `[self initWithFrame:]`.

You can read more about this topic in Apple's official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW3

Answer (score 2):

I Guess that `[UIView init]` is calling `[self initWithFrame:CGRectZero]`, so it's calling your own `initWithFrame` method since you have overloaded it.

To solve your problems you should simply do the same :).
`init` should call `initWithFrame` and not the opposite.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that before asking the question and it worked perfectly, I just wanted to know why is that the normal behavior. I could not find anything in the documentation. PS. I am now going for a short trip, I will wait until I'm back to accept the answer in case someone has a better explanation.